# using if statement in .html template page (inside <span> tag)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, if-statement

Can anyone help me in using `if statement` in `.html` page.

I have a `etemplate.html` page. Inside its `<span>` tag i have some `{values}` which i am populating from code behind. like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border-top:3px solid #22BCE5">&nbsp;</div>
    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt">

        Hi <b>{Name}</b>,<br /><br />       
        Thank you for your order. Your project ID is {ProjId}. Your order 
        description is {description}.<br /><br />

  // for {summary} == "" the below code shows if(!=""){---...
  //I have tried using <% %> tags but not working

        if({summary}!=""){
          Your project summary is {summary}.
        }
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

And my populating method in c# is:

```
private string PopulateConfirmationEmailBody(string Name, string ProjId, 
string description, string summary)
        {
            string body = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new 
            StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/etemplate.html")))
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            body = body.Replace("{Name}", Name);
            body = body.Replace("{ProjId}", ProjId);
            body = body.Replace("{description}", description);
            body = body.Replace("{summary}", summary);
            return body;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Check this: https://forums.asp.net/t/1944993.aspx?How+to+use+if+else+condition+to+display+text+in+HTML+

Comment: @Sujith Thanks for suggestion but as i have mentioned i already tried using <% %> but not working

Comment: Right now you're not actually doing anything to run the code in your html.  You need to run it through a parser like Razor that will run the embedded code and output plain html.

Comment: @juharr I have no idea about Razor can you plz explain how to use this. In my code every other html tag is working fine but only if not even not inside<% %>

Comment: @Preet That's not html.  That's additional code that is meant to be parsed and then the real html is created.  One of the newer parsers that .Net uses is [Razor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/) and you can create a razor template with embedded code and use that engine to generate html.  Note that Razor does have it's own syntax which is slightly different from what you currently have.  Also you wouldn't need to do the replaces that way either.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info. Actually my file is very long with lots of text paragraphs really don't wanna change the whole. Is there any way i can use in same syntax Thanks

Comment: Then you'd need an ASP parser.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that how can i use in my case. Thank you

Comment: @Preet If you wish to keep it as just HTML, you can probably change the code on server side to this:  if(!String.IsNullorEmpty(summary))body = body.Replace("{summary}", "Your project summary is: " + summary); else {body.Replace("{summary}", String.Empty);}     and in HTML just use {summary}    --> By this you are trying to apply conditions on the server side and don't need to use <%%> on client

Comment: @Sujith thank you. It will work!! actually I have lot of text inside if so it will become complicated or i have to write all in strings in code behind. looking for some shorter solution or at last will do it like this

Comment: @Preet Other way is to write some simple parser or  a simple method to check if the HTML has anything like  <%if%> and evaluate a condition and replace text inside. This might have some impact on performance(load time) of the page,but this would be simple to implement, if you want to parse only a condition like IF. If you have multiple types of conditions then this parsing code becomes fairly complex, then it's better to convert your html to cshmtl/aspx

Comment: yeah, will try like this as well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting parsed as HTML, because the very last thing you're writing before the `if` is a `<br />` tag. Because you never tell the parser that you're attempting to write C# code, it thinks that `if` is a literal HTML string of `if` that should be outputted to the page.

You need to use `<%` and `%>` codes for **both** the start and end of the `if` condition, as you're writing HTML **inside** of it, which would throw another parsing error otherwise.

```
<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt">
    Hi <b>{Name}</b>,<br /><br />       
    Thank you for your order. Your project ID is {ProjId}. Your order 
    description is {description}.<br /><br />

    <% if({summary}!="") { %>
      Your project summary is {summary}.
    <% } %>

</span>
```

Either use two separate sets of `<% %>` as above, or explicitly state that you're writing HTML with `Response.Write()`:

```
<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt">
    Hi <b>{Name}</b>,<br /><br />       
    Thank you for your order. Your project ID is {ProjId}. Your order 
    description is {description}.<br /><br />

    <% if({summary}!="") {
      Response.Write("Your project summary is {summary}.");
    <% }

</span>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help but it is not working for me I tried using these tags

Comment: Can you plz explain how to use response.write for the same. Thanks

Comment: Updated to cover that.

Comment: No it is displaying Response.Write("your summary is: ");. Dont know whats i am doing wrong!

Comment: @ObsidianAge I believe the OP is trying to generate raw html, not html that will then be parsed server side.